# How to assign a unique identifier to unique collections of data frame values across different groups of columns?

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks similar to this:

```
teamAPlayer1    teamAPlayer2    teamBPlayer1    teamBPlayer2
Jack            Jill            Matt            Megan
Jill            Jack            Megan           Matt
Megan           Jill            Matt            Jack
Megan           Matt            Jill            Jack
Megan           Jack            Jill            Matt
```

My goal is to assign a unique ID to each unique team lineup, regardless of player numbers and whether they are on team A or team B. For the above example, I'd like to add the following two columns to my data frame:

```
teamAPlayer1    teamAPlayer2    teamAID    teamBPlayer1    teamBPlayer2    teamBID
Jack            Jill            1          Matt            Megan           2
Jill            Jack            1          Megan           Matt            2
Megan           Jill            3          Matt            Jack            4
Megan           Matt            2          Jill            Jack            1
Jack            Matt            4          Jill            Megan           3
```

I could write a solution indexing with for/while loops, but I'm working on a very large data frame and with 5 players per team instead of 2 so it would take a long time for the script to run. Is it possible to solve this with a vectorized method?

Comment: you've received a lot of answers below. If one of them solved your issue please consider accepting it as an answer. This lets the community know the answer worked and that your issue should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Your data

```
df <- data.frame(teamAPlayer1=c("Jack","Jill","Megan","Megan","Megan"),
                 teamAPlayer2=c("Jill","Jack","Jill","Matt","Jack"),
                 teamBPlayer1=c("Matt","Megan","Matt","Jill","Jill"),
                 teamBPlayer2=c("Megan","Matt","Jack","Jack","Matt"),
                 stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Make vector of unique player names

```
# Grab all unique player names - assign to each a number
unique.id <- seq(1, length(unique(unlist(df))), 1)
names(unique.id) <- unique(unlist(df))

# Paste and sort player pair combinations in new columns
df1 <- df %>%
   rowwise() %>%
   mutate(teamApairs=paste0(sort(c(unique.id[teamAPlayer1],unique.id[teamAPlayer2])),collapse=" ")) %>%
   mutate(teamBpairs=paste0(sort(c(unique.id[teamBPlayer1],unique.id[teamBPlayer2])),collapse=" ")) %>%
```

Make vector of unique player pairs

```
# Grab all unique player pairs - assign to each a unique number
unique.pairs <- seq(1, length(unique(unlist(df1[,5:6]))), 1)
names(unique.pairs) <- unique(unlist(df1[,5:6]))

# Factorize unique player pairs as unique number
df2 <- df1 %>%
       mutate(teamAID=unique.pairs[teamApairs]) %>%
       mutate(teamBID=unique.pairs[teamBpairs]) %>%
       select(-teamApairs,-teamBpairs)
```

Output

```
  teamAPlayer1 teamAPlayer2 teamBPlayer1 teamBPlayer2 teamAID teamBID
1         Jack         Jill         Matt        Megan       1       3
2         Jill         Jack        Megan         Matt       1       3
3        Megan         Jill         Matt         Jack       2       5
4        Megan         Matt         Jill         Jack       3       1
5        Megan         Jack         Jill         Matt       4       6
```

Answer (score 0):

Your output doesn't match your input (see last row), but I think this will get you what you want:

```
df <- read.table(text="teamAPlayer1    teamAPlayer2    teamBPlayer1    teamBPlayer2
Jack            Jill            Matt            Megan
Jill            Jack            Megan           Matt
Megan           Jill            Matt            Jack
Megan           Matt            Jill            Jack
Megan           Jack            Jill            Matt",stringsAsFactors=FALSE,header=TRUE)

dt_concat <- matrix(unlist(t(df)),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE) %>% # create a two column matrix with team compositions
  cbind(.,team = apply(.,1,. %>% sort %>% paste(collapse=" "))) %>% as.data.table # add column with sorted team members in a string
dt_concat[, teamID := .GRP, by = team] # attribute ids
df %<>% cbind(dt_concat$teamID %>% matrix(ncol=2,byrow=TRUE) %>% set_colnames(c("teamAID","teamBID"))) # add ids to original df

#   teamAPlayer1 teamAPlayer2 teamBPlayer1 teamBPlayer2 teamAID teamBID
# 1         Jack         Jill         Matt        Megan       1       2
# 2         Jill         Jack        Megan         Matt       1       2
# 3        Megan         Jill         Matt         Jack       3       4
# 4        Megan         Matt         Jill         Jack       2       1
# 5        Megan         Jack         Jill         Matt       5       6
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution using `pmin` and `pmax`

```
v1 <- paste(do.call(pmin, df[c(1:2)]), do.call(pmax, df[c(1:2)]))
v2 <- paste(do.call(pmin, df[c(3:4)]), do.call(pmax, df[c(3:4)]))
v3 <- unique(c(rbind(v1, v2)))

teamAID <- match(v1, v3)
#[1] 1 1 3 2 5

teamBID <- match(v2, v3)
#[1] 2 2 4 1 6
```

Comment: This won't work if some couples are only in one team (i.e. try `df <- df[-4,]`)

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper you are right. Edited to include that case

Answer (score 0):

Permit me to suggest that you reshape your original data entirely.

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
setDT(df)

df %>%
  .[, Round := 1:.N] %>%
  .[]  # this is only here to view the result

   teamAPlayer1 teamAPlayer2 teamBPlayer1 teamBPlayer2 Round
1:         Jack         Jill         Matt        Megan     1
2:         Jill         Jack        Megan         Matt     2
3:        Megan         Jill         Matt         Jack     3
4:        Megan         Matt         Jill         Jack     4
5:        Megan         Jack         Jill         Matt     5
```

That is, each row in your original data is identified by `Round` (the round of a tournament). You can then reshape your data:

```
df %>%
  .[, Round := 1:.N] %>%
  melt.data.table(id.vars = "Round",
                  value.name = "participant") %>%
  .[, Event := gsub("team([AB]).*$", "\\1", variable)] %>%
  # Ordering by participant necessary to define
  # distinct combinations  JackJill == JillJack
  .[order(Round, participant, Event)] %>%
  .[,
    .(Team = paste0(participant, collapse = "")),
    keyby = .(Round, Event)]

    Round Event      Team
 1:     1     A  JackJill
 2:     1     B MattMegan
 3:     2     A  JackJill
 4:     2     B MattMegan
 5:     3     A JillMegan
 6:     3     B  JackMatt
 7:     4     A MattMegan
 8:     4     B  JackJill
 9:     5     A JackMegan
10:     5     B  JillMatt
```

There are many advantages to this format. For example you could add another column 'Score' which would unambiguously refer to a particular game, rather than relying on the order of columns. However, if you wanted something closer to your original, you can always you `dcast`:

```
df %>%
  .[, Round := 1:.N] %>%
  melt.data.table(id.vars = "Round",
                  value.name = "participant") %>%
  .[, Event := gsub("team([AB]).*$", "\\1", variable)] %>%
  # Ordering by participant necessary to define
  # distinct combinations  JackJill == JillJack
  .[order(Round, participant, Event)] %>%
  .[,
    .(Team = paste0(participant, collapse = "")),
    keyby = .(Round, Event)] %>%
  dcast.data.table(Round ~ Event)

   Round         A         B
1:     1  JackJill MattMegan
2:     2  JackJill MattMegan
3:     3 JillMegan  JackMatt
4:     4 MattMegan  JackJill
5:     5 JackMegan  JillMatt
```